# Why is an Array an abstract class in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

The Array class in C# is an abstract class even though it doesn't seem to have any abstract methods in it. Why is the Array Class in C# an abstract class?

I am aware that one cannot create an instance of Array using the new keyword since its abstract, but one can create an array using Array.CreateInstance(). I am curious if instantiation is the only reason why Array is an abstract class?

Comment: From the docs: *Provides methods for creating, manipulating, searching, and sorting arrays, thereby serving as the **base class** for all arrays in the common language runtime.*

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8) is a good place to start if you have questions. Look at why its abstract and what it implements

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999944/why-does-c-sharp-allow-for-an-abstract-class-with-no-abstract-members

Comment: Asking why a language feature was made is as futile as it is unrewarding. The only people that can truly answer are the people who made that decision. However what we do know is what we find in the documentation.

Comment: This might be illuminating ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163332/c-sharp-where-do-arrays-inherit-from-i-e-int

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does C# allow for an abstract class with no abstract members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999944/why-does-c-sharp-allow-for-an-abstract-class-with-no-abstract-members)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful responses. I guess the link posted by @Mick was helpful

Comment: Link posted by @SathishGuru was helpful too. Thanks!